# HTML, CSS - How to make element a scoll to div in other div with overflow-y: scroll;

Tags: html, css

How to make this "a href="#koszulki"]SCROLL TO 'KOSZULKI' /a" scroll to div in div with overflow-y: scroll;
Somebody knows how to do it? I have no idea how could i do it. Thanks!

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #content{
            overflow-y: scroll;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <a href="#koszulki">SCROLL TO 'KOSZULKI'</a>
        <div id="content">
            <section id="produkty">
                <div id="koszulki">
                    <div class="produkt">
                        <!-- CONTENT !-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="produkt">
                        <!-- CONTENT !-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="produkt">
                        <!-- CONTENT !-->
                    </div>      
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="bluzy">
                    <div class="produkt">
                        <!-- CONTENT !-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="produkt">
                        <!-- CONTENT !-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="produkt">
                        <!-- CONTENT !-->
                    </div>      
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey hermes what do you mean by scroll to div like when you click ur anchor tag you want the webpage scroll to a specific div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how to scroll to a div

```js
function scrollToDiv() {
  const bounds = document.getElementById("there").getBoundingClientRect()
  window.scrollTo(0, bounds.bottom);
}

document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0].onclick= () => scrollToDiv()
```

```css
body {
height: 3000px;
display : flex;
flex-direction : column;
justify-content: space-between;
margin : 50px;
}

.there {

}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<button>scroll there</button>
<div id="there">come here<div>
```

Comment: Yea thats kinda what i needed but im not scorlling window but <div id="content> i've just edited to this document.getElementById("content").scrollTo(0, bounds.bottom); and its working perfectly. Thank a lot! I have one more Q how to make this scroll animated or simply smooth?